# how can detect a php file is still running on apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script with an unlimited while, it must run 24/7

1. in another php file, how can I check is that file running on server or stopped?
2. how can i send a signal to apache to stop and re-execute that file?

Comment: Why would you run something like that as a never ending request to apache and not as whatever service abstraction your os provides?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assign numbers to files. The file that is running 24/7 will be `the first file` and the file that will change the state of the first one will be called `the second file`.
Now, the first file can write to a file or in database, let's say, every 10 minutes. This way you know if it's running by checking that file and the last date when it wrote that file. So you create a second file or database table and write in it the state you want the first file to be. Example: active or disabled. Now you read the file/table with the first file, if it's disabled, you stop executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

easiest might be to save timestamped status in memcache or other shared location, and have the other php script check the status timestamp

it's easy to kill an apache process and hit the page again, that will restart the script.  Or you can add a signal handler to restart on SIGHUP

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check whether a specific file is running. You'll have to check whether a *process* is still running with that file. That also means this isn't something Apache can do for you. You'll either have to:

1) use an OS-dependant kill-signal to the process running the script
2) check for a kill-signal from inside the script

The former requires a lot of privilige on the server, so it's probably easier to do the second.

The easiest way is for the running file to write to a database or file somewhere to signify that it´s still going, and to read the same location for a signal to stop every so often. If the running process sees a stop-signal, it can simply break from whatever loop is keeping it going.

The second script can set the signal at whatever point and for whatever reason, and the other script will quickly after terminate.

Answer (score 0):

If the first script terminates, write a file to a disk called error.txt, and then make the second script check for this every minute or so.

The second script once spots an error.txt file will be signaled to restart your first script. More realtime would be to use a database and with the current timestamp.